# Map to another map. To much code. Has more simple solution?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

Android Studio 3.6

Convert one map to another:
I need to replace in key's name the all "_" to space.

Here snippet of deserializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException

val pricesNode: JsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(pricesJson.toString())
        val fields: MutableIterator<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, JsonNode>>? =
            pricesNode.fields()
        val prices = HashMap<String, Double>()
        fields?.forEach {
            val fuelType = it.key.replace("_", " ")
            prices.put(fuelType, it.value.asDouble())
        }
```

but I think is too much code. Has more simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

show u the code

```
val map= mutableMapOf<String,String>()
        val newMap = map.mapKeys {
            it.key.replace("_", "")
        }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

```
val prices = objectMapper
  .readTree(json)
  .fields()
  ?.asSequence() // 1
  ?.map { it.key.replace("_", " ") to it.value.asDouble() }
  ?.toMap() ?: hashMapOf() // 2
```

if you will use `asSequence` (1) you can later use map to transform object the way you want.

Since you would like to get rid of null at the end and just have `Map<String,Double>` at the end you can use `?: hashMapOf()` at the end (2) so you will "transform" null to empty map

Comment: I posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
 val pricesJson = root["prices"].asJsonObject
        val pricesNode: JsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(pricesJson.toString())
        var pricesMap =
            objectMapper.convertValue<Map<String, Double>>(
                pricesNode,
                object :
                    TypeReference<Map<String?, Double?>?>() {})
        pricesMap = pricesMap.map { it.key.replace("_", " ") to it.value }.toMap()
```

or like this:

```
val pricesNode: JsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(pricesJson.toString())
        val fields: MutableIterator<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, JsonNode>>? =
            pricesNode.fields()
        val pricesMap: Map<String, Double> =
            fields?.asSequence()?.associate { (k, v) -> k.replace("_", " ") to v.asDouble() }!!
```

Answer (score 0):

The intended way is to use `mapKeys`:

```
fields
   .mapKeys { it.key.replace("_", " ") }
```

But since it looks like you're mapping both keys and values, you can do:

```
fields.entries
    .associate { (k, v)-> k.replace("_", " ") to v.toDouble()}
```

Comment: No method mapKeys in type MutableIterator<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, JsonNode>>